# SonarQube Objective C plugin is commercial?

Tags: objective-c, sonarqube

I'm trying to research ability of SonarQube on our xcode project. I install every nessessary things: oclint, gcovr, xctool, sonar runner and sonar server. But when I build project to analyze by Sonar it throw exception like this:

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: No license for objc
```

Can anybody understand why? I installed Objective C plugin in sonar server successfully but why it throw these exceptions? Thank you very much
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the Objective-C plugin for SonarQube is commercial: http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/objective-c/

There is however an alternative free version on GitHub: https://github.com/octo-technology/sonar-objective-c

I don't have any experience with either of them but maybe this helps.

Comment: how to install this plugin